# How do I set the operating directory in a script in rc.d (FreeBSD)?

Tags: freebsd, rc

I have a rc.d script that fires up a program that normally looks for a configuration file in ~/.app/app.conf. However, when I use `service app start` (or when it is auto-started at startup), the app complains that it cannot find the conf file in /.app/app.conf (the root directory). Is there a way that I can setup the script so that the operating directory is ~/ - in this case ~/ = /root/

Thanks.

Comment: Add `HOME=/ export HOME` in the script before you call the program itself

Comment: `export HOME=/root` would be better :)